# Reinstalling a deleted app on my iPad with iOS 6

Tags: ipad, ios-appstore

How can I restore an app on my iPad that I thought I didn't want, and deleted?  The App Store only lets me "open", not install. I want to know how I can get the icon back on my iPad.

Comment: If it is displayed with "Open" in the store, it's actually still installed on the iPad. You can use Spotlight to search for it.

Answer (score 1):

- Open App Store.
- click updates
- select Purchased
- change the tab from All to Not on This iPad

If it has been deleted it should have the cloud with the down arrow.
If it just says open, it could be that you haven't deleted it yet.... try swiping to the far left and using search... search for the app.
If you are having issues, turn off your ipad and back on again by holding down the power button then swipping to turn it off.